# How to replace Hex Characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, ascii, hexadecimal

```
    var x = {
    'leaderboardNick': {
        'Player': '\x72\x67\x62\x61\x28\x32\x32\x32\x2c\x20\x32\x33\x2c\x20\x38\x38\x2c\x20\x31\x29',
        '\u3010\u20B1\u20AC\u3011': #FFF,
    },
    'emoticons': {},
    'indicator': {},
    'indicatorMaxSize': 0xc8
 };
```

How can I change this chars (0xc8,\u3010,\x72) with ascii? I have so much word in my text.

Like this;

```
var x = {
    'leaderboardNick': {
        'Player': 'rgba(222, 23, 88, 1)',
        '【₱€】': #FFF,
    },
    'emoticons': {},
    'indicator': {},
    'indicatorMaxSize': 200
};
```

Comment: If you change all the `\x` to `\u00` then you could use the [HTMLTag plug-in for Notepad++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/HTMLTag/) to decode to UTF.

Comment: it is works but what I need for this?
0xc8

Comment: I think you might have to use a script to do that as it is a different kind of transformation. If there aren't many to do, then [Decimal-hexadecimal-binary conversion table](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afdl).

Comment: I have so much like this. (1000+) Also I didn't find script for "hex to decimal" conversation.

Comment: Unless someone comes up with an answer, you could learn a programming language to do it. There are many languages you could use, but as Python in popular at the moment and available on many platforms, you could start at [Beginner's Guide to Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide).